# How can I get the year, month, and day from a Deephaven DateTime in Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a Deephaven DateTime in the New York (US-East) timezone and I'd like to get the year, month, and day (of the month) numbers from it as integers in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Deephaven's `time` module has these utilities.  You may have used it to create a Deephaven DateTime in the first place.

```py
from deephaven import time as dhtu

timestamp = dhtu.to_datetime("2022-04-01T12:00:00 NY")
```

The following three methods will give you what you're looking for:

- `year` - Gets the year
- `month_of_year` - Gets the month
- `day_of_month` - Gets the day of the month

All three methods will give you what you want based on the DateTime itself and your preferred time zone.

```py
tz_ny = dhtu.TimeZone.NY

year = dhtu.year(timestamp, tz_ny)
month = dhtu.month_of_year(timestamp, tz_ny)
day = dhtu.day_of_month(timestamp, tz_ny)
```